# Is it possible to get user input from email without opening browser?

Tags: email, browser, input

I'm sending users on a website an email requesting a yes or no answer and I want to know if there's a way of getting their response without having them clicking links in the email (disguised with html as buttons). I've tried searching but there didn't seem to be anything suitable.

The nuisance with clicking the links is that this has to open a browser to follow the link.

//Is it possible to get their response without taking them away from the email client/browser?

Edit: Is it possible to get their response without making them navigate away from the email

Comment: Add 'Please reply with Yes or No' in the signature and stay on top of it? Or set a 'Reply-To' header to an e-mail address you can scrape the e-mails from.

Comment: There's thousands of these emails so writing and monitoring an email scraper doesn't sound appealing. thanks though. Edited question